# c# Dictionary with HashSet<int> as value get intersection of all

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, intersection, hashset

I have a Dictionary with HashSet as Value. I have an int[] with the keys for which I want to get the Count of common values in the HashSet's.

Here is a piece of code that works in a very inefficient way as it requires to create a HashSet and modify it in memory before the final Count.

```
        Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> d = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

        HashSet<int> s1 = new HashSet<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        HashSet<int> s2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8 };
        HashSet<int> s3 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20 };
        HashSet<int> s4 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 20 };

        d.Add(10, s1);
        d.Add(15, s2);
        d.Add(20, s3);
        d.Add(25, s4);

        // List of keys from which I need the intersection of the HashSet's
        int[] l = new int[3] { 10, 15, 20 };

        // Get an IEnumerator with the HashSet from the values of the selected Dictionary entries (10,15,20 selects s1, s2 and s3)
        var hashlist = d.Where(x => l.Contains(x.Key));

        // Create a new HashSet to contain the intersection of all the HashSet's
        HashSet<int> first = new HashSet<int>(hashlist.First().Value);
        foreach (var hash in hashlist.Skip(1))
            first.IntersectWith(hash.Value);

        // Show the number of common int's
        Console.WriteLine("Common elements: {0}", first.Count);
```

What I am looking for is an efficient way (LinQ perhaps?) to count the common elements without having to create a new HashSet as I am running a similar code hundreds of millions of times.

It is also important to note that I create a new HashSet to get the intersections as I do not want to modify the original HashSet's.

Best regargs,
Jorge

Comment: If you used LinQ the only thing it is going to do is create a HashSet behind the scenes to do it, in fact it will likely be more inefficient because it will need to make a new set for every step of the union.

Comment: Do you currently have a performance issue?

Comment: Do you have a range that you know you're numbers will always be in?

Comment: Enigmativity, the problem is that I have to get the count thousands of millions of times with different combinations of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

This can definitely be improved:

```
var hashlist = d.Where(x => l.Contains(x.Key));
```

By rewriting it as:

```
var hashlist = l.Select(x => d[x]);
```

This will take advantage of the `Dictionary`'s internal `HashSet` to efficiently get the value at the specific key rather than repeatedly iterating over the `int[]`.

Your next big problem is that [Linq is lazy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-and-in-contrast-eager-evaluation/), so by calling `Fist()` and `Skip(1)` separately, you're actually requiring multiple enumerations over the collection using the previously mentioned `Where(…)` filter.

To avoid multiple enumerations, you could rewrite this:

```
HashSet<int> first = new HashSet<int>(hashlist.First().Value);
foreach (var hash in hashlist.Skip(1))
     first.IntersectWith(hash.Value);
```

As:

```
var intersection = hashlist.Aggregate(
    (HashSet<int>)null, 
    (h, j) => 
    {
        if (h == null)
            h = new HashSet<int>(j);
        else 
            h.IntersectWith(j);
        return h; 
    });
```

But depending on your precise use case it may just be faster (and easier to understand) to simply materialize the result into a `List` first, then use a simple `for` loop:

```
var hashlist = l.Select(x => d[x]).ToList();

HashSet<int> first = hashlist[0];
for (var i = 0; i < hashlist.Count; i++)
     first.IntersectWith(hashlist[i]);
```

Here's a quick benchmark with these various options (your results may vary):

```
Original        2.285680 (ms)
SelectHashList  1.912829 
Aggregate       1.815872 
ToListForLoop   1.608565 
OrderEnumerator 1.975067 // Scott Chamberlain's answer
EnumeratorOnly  1.732784 // Scott Chamberlain's answer without the call to OrderBy()
AggIntersect    2.046930 // P. Kouvarakis's answer (with compiler error fixed)
JustCount       1.260448 // Ivan Stoev's updated answer
```

Comment: Instead of Aggregate, in special cases like this I normally just stop using a foreach and switch over to using the raw `IEnumerator`, it can be handy when you want to do special stuff the first iteration you don't want to happen on other iterations.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's a good point. I often forget about that as an option.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks. All the tests were running noticeably faster this morning (I guess closing one instance of VS will do that) so I updated the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

> What I am looking for is an **efficient** way (LinQ perhaps?) to **count** the common elements

If you really wish maximum performance, forget about LINQ, here is an old school way with all possible optimizations (that I can think of) applied:

```
// Collect the non empty matching sets, keeping the set with the min Count at position 0
var sets = new HashSet<int>[l.Length];
int setCount = 0;
foreach (var key in l)
{
    HashSet<int> set;
    if (!d.TryGetValue(key, out set) || set.Count == 0) continue;
    if (setCount == 0 || sets[0].Count <= set.Count)
        sets[setCount++] = set;
    else
    {
        sets[setCount++] = sets[0];
        sets[0] = set;
    }
}
int commonCount = 0;
if (setCount > 0)
{
    if (setCount == 1)
        commonCount = sets[0].Count;
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in sets[0])
        {
            bool isCommon = true;
            for (int i = 1; i < setCount; i++)
                if (!sets[i].Contains(item)) { isCommon = false; break; }
            if (isCommon) commonCount++;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Common elements: {0}", commonCount);
```

Hope the code is self explanatory.

Comment: Ivan, Thanks a lot. The time with a small test set went from 14.6813333 seconds down to 5.3198979 seconds. I will now run against the big file to see the real impact of the change.

Comment: Couldn't you move that `for` that calculates `minCountPos` to be part of the `if` statement in the first `foreach` loop? That gets rid of one of the enumerations of `setList`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Absolutely, thank you! Now when thinking, I can get rid of that variable and keep the set with min count at index 0, thus eliminating the `i != minCountPos` condition inside the innermost loop.

Comment: Updated with additional optimizations inspired by @ScottChamberlain comment, plus replacing the list with array (one less heap allocation).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks you could do that could potentially buy you a lot of speed up. The biggest one I see is start with the smallest set first, then work your way up to larger ones, this gives the initial set the smallest possible amount of stuff to intersect with, giving faster lookups.

Also, if you manually build your ienumerable instead of using a `foreach` you don't need to enumerate the list twice (EDIT: also use the trick [p.s.w.g mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979511/80274), select against the dictionary instead of using a `.Contains(`).

***Important Note:*** this method will only give you benefits if you are combining a large number of HashSets with a wide range of item counts. The overhead of calling `OrderBy` will be significant and in a small dataset like you have in your example and it is unlikely you will see any benefit.

```
Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> d = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

HashSet<int> s1 = new HashSet<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
HashSet<int> s2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8 };
HashSet<int> s3 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20 };
HashSet<int> s4 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 20 };

d.Add(10, s1);
d.Add(15, s2);
d.Add(20, s3);
d.Add(25, s4);

// List of keys from which I need the intersection of the HashSet's
int[] l = new int[3] { 10, 15, 20 };

HashSet<int> combined;
//Sort in increasing order by count
//Also used the trick from p.s.w.g's answer to get a better select.
IEnumerable<HashSet<int>> sortedList = l.Select(x => d[x]).OrderBy(x => x.Count);

using (var enumerator = sortedList.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        combined = new HashSet<int>(enumerator.Current);
    }
    else
    {
        combined = new HashSet<int>();
    }

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        combined.IntersectWith(enumerator.Current);
    }
}


// Show the number of common int's
Console.WriteLine("Common elements: {0}", combined.Count);
```

Comment: Explicitly using the `Enumerator` is a big improvement, but the `OrderBy` is relatively costly. See my updated benchmark. Of course, this depends greatly on the precise data involved.

Comment: Yep, i saw your timing in your answer and had a head slap moment, I added a disclaimer to the answer about the dangers of the overhead cost of the `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

`IntersectWith()' is probably as efficient as you can get.

Using LINQ you could make code cleaner (?):

```
var result = l.Aggregate(null, (acc, key) => acc == null? d[key] : acc.Intersect(d[key]));
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't compile (you have to specify a type for `null`), but if you fix that, it's faster than the original. I'll update by benchmark shortly.